# Display data from JSON file in html div

Tags: javascript, html, json

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@600&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.801);
    font-family: Orbitron;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.title {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0 70px 0;
}

.categorys p {
    display: inline;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 230px;
}

.col p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    font-size: 24px;
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 230px;
}

.scores {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pygame Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="title">Leaderboard</h1>
    <div class="container categorys">
        <p>Time</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Points</p>
    </div>
    <div class="scores">

        <div class="col">
            <p>02.03 15:43</p>
            <p>02.03 17:05</p>
            <p>02.03 17:05</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>chraebsli</p>
            <p>awd</p>
            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>1080</p>
            <p>233</p>
            <p>133</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a JSON file named scores.json (an example below). I want to display the time, name and points in a HTML file in a div. How can I do that?

> And I never use JS so please give me a full code and don't mark it as a duplicate, I already studied many other questions but I don't understand how to change it for my problem.

I now also inserted an example how it should look like (I know it isn't responsive and doesn't look well but that's how it should look like )

HTML div:

```html
<div class="container scores">
```

scores.json:

```json
{
    "scores": [{
            "time": "02.03 15:43",
            "name": "chraebsli",
            "points": 1080
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "awd",
            "points": 233
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 133
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:06",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 307
        },
        {
            "time": "03.03 14:06",
            "name": "d",
            "points": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would you like to have it as a table in HTML?

Comment: @NikhilSingh no I want it as single p elements 
I will upload an example how I want it just a moment please

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with other work. Just saw the message. Happy you got the answer :)

Comment: @NikhilSingh no problem everybody have better things to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on petyor's solution I have further elaborated/showed how you will actually do this:

```js
let data = {
    "scores": [{
            "time": "02.03 15:43",
            "name": "chraebsli",
            "points": 1080
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "awd",
            "points": 233
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 133
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:06",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 307
        },
        {
            "time": "03.03 14:06",
            "name": "d",
            "points": 30
        }
    ]
};

let times = names = points = '<div class="col">';
for(let d in data.scores) {
    times += `<p>${data.scores[d].time}</p>`;
    names += `<p>${data.scores[d].name}</p>`;
    points += `<p>${data.scores[d].points}</p>`;
}
[times, names, points].map(i => i + '</div>').join('');
document.getElementById("times").innerHTML = times;
document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = names;
document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@600&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.801);
    font-family: Orbitron;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.title {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0 70px 0;
}

.categorys p {
    display: inline;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 230px;
}
.col{float:left;}
.col p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
    font-size: 24px;
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 230px;
}

.scores {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pygame Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="title">Leaderboard</h1>
    <div class="container categorys">
        <p>Time</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Points</p>
    </div>
    <div class="scores" id="scores">

        <div class="col" id="times">
       <!--     <p>02.03 15:43</p>
            <p>02.03 17:05</p>
            <p>02.03 17:05</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="names">
        <!--    <p>chraebsli</p>
            <p>awd</p>
            <p>lol</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="points">
           <!-- <p>1080</p>
            <p>233</p>
            <p>133</p> -->
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
let data = {
    "scores": [{
            "time": "02.03 15:43",
            "name": "chraebsli",
            "points": 1080
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "awd",
            "points": 233
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:05",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 133
        },
        {
            "time": "02.03 17:06",
            "name": "lol",
            "points": 307
        },
        {
            "time": "03.03 14:06",
            "name": "d",
            "points": 30
        }
    ]
};

let times = names = points = '<div class="col">';
for(let d in data.scores) {
    times += `<p>${data.scores[d].time}</p>`;
    names += `<p>${data.scores[d].name}</p>`;
    points += `<p>${data.scores[d].points}</p>`;
}
const result = [times, names, points].map(i => i + '</div>').join('');
$('.scores').append(result); // Via jQuery
document.getElementsByClassName('scores')[0].innerHTML += result; // Via vanilla Javascript
```

It returns a string with the three divs. You just need to render it on the page.

Comment: thanks but where I have to place the code?
I placed it in the div and above and below but it doesn't work
Can you tell me why?

Comment: Considering the description you want it inside the `scores` div so you can do something like this: `$('.scores').append(result)` where `result` is the value that is returned from the last line. I'll edit my answer so you can see it clearer.

Comment: I've provided two ways of appending the text to the div, check them out.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know why it doesn't work but I think I placed it at the false position.
It has to be in the head element hasn't it?

Comment: Just put the code inside a `<script></script>` tag at the bottom of the `body` before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: Okey I did it but I think im just dumb and it doesn't work because of a mistake I din't see